# Using playwright for python, how can I click a button?

Tags: python, xpath, playwright, playwright-python

First time using playwright. Trying to log in to Pinterest.

```
browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
context = browser.new_context()

page = context.new_page()
page.goto('https://pinterest.co.uk/login')

# Interact with login form
page.fill('input[name="id"]', email)
page.fill('input[name="password"]', password)

# looking for the login button. This part breaks.
page.locator('xpath=//*[@id="__PWS_ROOT__"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[4]/form/div[5]/button').click()


#open the form to create a pin
page.goto('https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin-builder/')
```

I get a timeout error because it's waiting for the selector with the given xpath, but it's probably not finding it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get that button by text:

```
page.locator('"Log in"').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one hope it will work for your machine too.
you cannot use `xpath` in all the places it leads to some unwanted errors anytime so use `has-text`

```
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright, expect


def run(playwright: Playwright) -> None:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context()

    # Open new page
    page = context.new_page()

    # Go to https://www.pinterest.co.uk/login/
    page.goto("https://www.pinterest.co.uk/login/")

    # Click [placeholder="Email"]
    page.locator("[placeholder=\"Email\"]").click()

    # Fill [placeholder="Email"]
    page.locator("[placeholder=\"Email\"]").fill("xxxxx@gmail.com")

    # Click [placeholder="Password"]
    page.locator("[placeholder=\"Password\"]").click()

    # Fill [placeholder="Password"]
    page.locator("[placeholder=\"Password\"]").fill("password")

    # Click button:has-text("Log in")
    # with page.expect_navigation(url="https://www.pinterest.co.uk/"):
    with page.expect_navigation():
        page.locator("button:has-text(\"Log in\")").click()

    # ---------------------
    context.close()
    browser.close()


with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    run(playwright)
```